# How to add years to a column of dates in R

Tags: r, lubridate

The data I am working with only includes the day of the month and the month like so:

```
  date  time  sales 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 11/08 09:00 84.15 
2 11/08 10:00 503.08
3 11/08 11:00 674.25
4 11/08 12:00 596.75
5 11/08 13:00 338.05
6 11/08 14:00 343.35
```

Is there a way to add the year onto the date section to replicate this:

```
  date       time  sales 
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> 
1 11/08/2022 09:00 84.15 
2 11/08/2022 10:00 503.08
3 11/08/2022 11:00 674.25
4 11/08/2022 12:00 596.75
5 11/08/2022 13:00 338.05
6 11/08/2022 14:00 343.35
```

I wish to ultimately use lubridate to add a new column that shows the actual day of the week according to the date; however, I could not find a way to do it without the year being included in the date.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How do you know which year it is?

Comment: Based on where I downloaded the data from. The csv file unfortunately does not include the year.

Answer (score 1):

You could first add `/2022` using `paste0` to your character column and use `weekdays` from `lubridate` with `as.Date` to get the week day like this:

```r
df$date = paste0(df$date, "/2022")
library(lubridate)
df$week_day = weekdays(as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
df
#>         date  time  sales week_day
#> 1 11/08/2022 09:00  84.15 Thursday
#> 2 11/08/2022 10:00 503.08 Thursday
#> 3 11/08/2022 11:00 674.25 Thursday
#> 4 11/08/2022 12:00 596.75 Thursday
#> 5 11/08/2022 13:00 338.05 Thursday
#> 6 11/08/2022 14:00 343.35 Thursday
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>